# switch xcopy to robocopy

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I am using the following script.  When I swap out the "move" with "robocopy /mov /mt" it doesn't work.  The destination goes one level too deep and takes the name of the file as the destination folder.  Error is below too.

How can I use robocopy instead?  I need the multithreading.

Error=
ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Accessing Source Directory D:\source\FILE.tif\
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET Source=D:\source
SET Destination=D:\dest

Echo Gather Top 30 files
set SrcCount=0
set SrcMax=31
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%a IN ('dir /A-D /O-D /B "%Source%"\*.*') DO (
    SET /A SrcCount += 1
    if !SrcCount! LEQ %SrcMax% (
MOVE "%source%\%%a" "%destination%
  )
)
```

This is what I am trying:

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET Source=D:\source
SET Destination=D:\dest

Echo Gather Top 30 files
set SrcCount=0
set SrcMax=31
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%a IN ('dir /A-D /O-D /B "%Source%"\*.*') DO (
    SET /A SrcCount += 1
    if !SrcCount! LEQ %SrcMax% (
robocopy /mov /mt "%source%\%%a" "%destination%
  )
)
```

Comment: Open a console window, type `robocopy /?` and read the help; you will find that there is a different syntax, concerning source and destination, both are considered as directories; you should not guess the syntax...

Answer (score 1):

Look at the arguments to `robocopy`:

> **robocopy /?**
>
> ```
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>    ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>   Started : Wed Jun 01 18:46:40 2016
>
>               Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination [file [file]...] [options]
>
>              source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
>         destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
>                file :: File(s) to copy  (names/wildcards: default is "*.*").
> ```

The first argument is a *Source Directory*, not a file. You are passing a file name.

So, do this instead:

```
robocopy /mov /mt "%source%" "%destination%" "%%a"
```

---

As for the `/MT` option, I *think* the threads are used to copy *different* files, not different parts of the *same* file.

Since you only call it with one file at a time, I don't believe you'll actually get any multi-threaded copying.

You'll need to gather all 30 file names in a single string so the result after substitution will be a single execution of `robocopy` like this:

```
robocopy /mov /mt "sourceDir" "destDir" "file1" "file2" "file3" ... "file30"
```

Comment: Excellent sir, thank you.  Your answer on the first argument was spot on.  Fixed that issue.  I'm a scripting newbie...  As for the second answer on the /MT option.  I will have to research how to do this.  This is crucial to my script as I will need it to multi-thread over the network.  Synchronous will be too slow.